# perl - remove node from xml file

Tags: xml, perl, xml-parsing, xml-libxml

I have a XML file, and I want to read it - remove a node - save it.
I run perl from terminal (perl script.pl)

example XML (filename.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<twice>
    <inner>
        <twice>
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </twice>
        <twice>
            <name>Alan</name>
            <surname>Bowler</surname>
        </twice>
        <twice>
            <name>Michael</name>
            <surname>Deck</surname>
        </twice>
    </inner>
</twice>
```

example perl script (script.pl):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $filename = "filename.xml";
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $xmldoc = $parser->parse_file($filename);
for my $dead ($xmldoc->findnodes(q{/twice/inner/twice[surname = "Bowler"]})) {
    $dead->unbindNode;
}
print $xmldoc->toString;
```

Now it outputs the expected result in terminal, but without saving the file.
Expected result (filename.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<twice>
    <inner>
        <twice>
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </twice>
        <twice>
            <name>Michael</name>
            <surname>Deck</surname>
        </twice>
    </inner>
</twice>
```

I have searched for many hours and couldn't find anything, sorry if it's a duplicate!
This is my first experience with perl so please any help would be welcomed, thanks.

Comment: That is odd, it removed the Bowler record for me. Or do you mean that it prints to the terminal fine, but doesn't save the filename.xml?

Comment: exactly, it doesn't save the file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using toString the docs say to do it like this:

```
open my $out_fh, '>', 'somefile.xml';
print {$out_fh} $xmldoc->toString;
```

You can also use the `toFile()` function to save it:

```
$xmldoc->toFile("someFile.xml");
```

Edit: Also to quote the docs, (which is all I did) you can pass the format parameter to these functions.

> If $format is 0, than the document is dumped as it was originally
>   parsed
>
> If $format is 1, libxml2 will add ignorable white spaces, so the nodes
>   content is easier to read. Existing text nodes will not be altered
>
> If $format is 2 (or higher), libxml2 will act as $format == 1 but it
>   add a leading and a trailing line break to each text node.

Giving you:

```
$xmldoc->toFile("someFile.xml", $format);
```

or

```
print {$out_fh} $xmldoc->toString($format);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [App::Xml_grep2](http://metacpan.org/release/App-xml_grep2) to do this from the command line:

```
xml_grep2 -v '/twice/inner/twice[surname = "Bowler"]' input.xml > output_xml
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but I didn't mention that I am doing this from an iPhone