# Removing Tag and its parent from an XML using perl

Tags: xml, perl, nodes

Hi I am working on a perl script which would remove a node from the XML. I developed the script using the below post.

[perl - remove node from xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15214995/perl-remove-node-from-xml-file)

But once the node is removed, it is leaving the parent node blank and the application reading the XML is not liking it. Meaning application is not understanding the tag with spaces. So I want to delete the parent node as well with spaces.

From the below XML

```
<twice>
    <inner>
        <twice>
            <name>John</name>
            <surname>Smith</surname>
        </twice>
   </inner>
</twice>
```

my script is able to remove node 'twice' but leaving he node 'inner' with spaces

result:

```
<twice>
    <inner>

   </inner>
</twice>
```

But I want to remove the node 'inner' as well with its parent node without spaces.

expected result:

```
<twice>
</twice>
```

PS: I am not an expert of perl, so please ignore my mistakes.

Comment: Oh, come on! Just change the XPath query to select the parent node! (I'm not going to give you the result, because this is *really* trivial, and just requires two characters to be swapped…)

Answer (score 0):

I know, that LibXML is the proper way but I like regexps too :-)

```
$s =~ s!<inner>.*?</inner>!!gis;
```